# Compile PHP to exe and run error

Tags: php, compiler-errors

I am very new to PHP. 
I have this PHP file:

```
<?php
echo phpversion();
require_once("RA_API.php");
$RAConn = new RetroAchievements('xx', 'xxx' );
$data = $RAConn->GetConsoleIDs();
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++)
{
echo $data[$i]->ID;
echo "\n";
echo $data[$i]->Name;
echo "\n";
}
?>
```

This script runs fine on my webserver. There it shows PHP version 5.5.11.

Now I used Bambalam to make an .exe file out of it. That also worked. But when I now execute that file, I get the following output:

```
4.4.4 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONST, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in e:\\program files (x86)\\progging\\xampp\\htdocs\\RA_API.php on line 4\n"
```

Notice how it suddenly shows 4.4.4 as version (I believe that is the problem.) 
Here is the file where the error is:

```
<?php
    class RetroAchievements
    {
    const API_URL = 'http://retroachievements.org/API/';

    public $ra_user;
    public $ra_api_key;

    public function __construct( $user, $api_key )
    {
        $this->ra_user = $user;
        $this->ra_api_key = $api_key;
    }

    private function AuthQS()
    {
        return "?z=" . $this->ra_user . "&y=" . $this->ra_api_key;
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this?

Comment: You just want your php file to compile fine, right?

Comment: No it compiles fine, it just should run correctly :P

Comment: It compiles fine but is missing this dependency require_once("RA_API.php");...just create a new php file just like in my answer and compile that file

Comment: `const` was added in PHP 5.3. before that you had to use `define()`. If you're getting v4.4 then you're definitely compiling to an ancient/obsolete PHP version target.

Comment: @RobertRozas why is that dependency missing? The file is in the same folder as the script & exe

Comment: @MarcB ye youre right, it wont work as Bambalam can only compile to PHP4.

Comment: @MarcB please post your comment as an answer :)